# can not send pdf file correctly in email attachment via SKPSMTPMessage

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf, email-attachments

I havea problem to send pdf file correctly in email attachment via SKPSMTPMessage. I can only open it in webmail and not in Mail in Mac or Outlook in Windows. The file is correct before sending. But when I open it in Mail program in Mac it complains that the file is corrupted. I am sure I made something wrong when sending the mail.
Could you please help me to see what is wrong in the mail sending? Thanks a lot for your help!

```
 SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
testMsg.fromEmail       = @"xxxx";
testMsg.toEmail         = @"xxxx";

testMsg.relayHost       = @"xxxxxxx";
testMsg.requiresAuth    = YES;
testMsg.login           = @"xxxx";
testMsg.pass            = @"****";
testMsg.subject         = @"ppp";
testMsg.wantsSecure     = YES; 

testMsg.delegate = self;

//email contents
NSString * bodyMessage = [self getBodyMessage];  //this is just a function to make up mail content

NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                           bodyMessage ,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

NSMutableArray* parts   = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[parts addObject:plainPart];

    //send simple order
    NSString* fileName  = self.companyOrder.simpleOrder.pdfFileName;
    NSString *filePath  = self.companyOrder.simpleOrder.pdfFileLocation;
    NSData *fileData    = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    NSString* strFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/pdf;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"%@\"", fileName];

    NSString* strFormat2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"%@\"", fileName];

    NSDictionary *vcfPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             strFormat,kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                             strFormat2,kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,
                             [fileData encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];


    [parts addObject:vcfPart];

// Send the email with the plain part and message
testMsg.parts = parts;

[testMsg send];
```

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. Have you found any solution over this?

Comment: You have to get a correct version of the SKPSMTPMessage. The fix is                                 NSDictionary *vcfPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 strFormat,kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                                 strFormat2,kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,
                                 [fileData encodeWrappedBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];